# How to implement dot product in elasaticsearch-oss/opensearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

Elasticsearch [has](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/dense-vector.html) `dotProduct` function for `dense_vector` field type. Yet this function is not available in Elasticsearch OSS / AWS OpenSearch.

Is it possible to implement it within AWS Opensearch? I was thinking of KNN plugin and/or painless scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Opensearch 1.0 KNN module](https://opensearch.org/docs/1.0/search-plugins/knn/knn-score-script/) with KNN scoring script. You would need to set spacetype to `innerproduct`